# I just wrote a simple hello world program in Assembly. I made an object file but terminal keeps on giving me the same error over and over again

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, nasm

Here is the hello.asm file I made. when running the following line of code in the terminal it creates an object file: nasm -f macho64 -o hello.o ~/Desktop/hello.asm
after that when I have the object file I want to assemble it inn a binary file using the next lien of code: ld -macosx_version_min 10.14 -lSystem -o hello hello.o

but I keep on getting the same error every time. this is the error I keep on getting: ld: library not found for -lSystem

Also I am on an M2 Mac mini if that helps to clarify why I am using ARM64 instead of ARM32

I am almost there but the library error keeps on holding me back. I've been trying to trouble shoot for the past 3 hrs!!!! Please help/

```
section .data
    hello db "Hello, World!", 0
    len equ $-hello

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    ; write "Hello, World!" to stdout
    mov eax, 1      ; system call for write
    mov edi, 1      ; file descriptor for stdout
    mov rsi, hello  ; pointer to string
    mov edx, len    ; string length
    syscall         ; invoke the system call

    ; exit the program with status code 0
    xor edi, edi    ; exit status code 0
    mov eax, 60     ; system call for exit
    syscall         ; invoke the system call

main:
    ; call the _start function
    call _start

    ; return 0
    mov eax, 0
    ret
```

I tried uninstalling Xcode directory files and reinstalling it, I tried uninstalling brew but that wasn't the issue.

Comment: `mov eax, 60` / `syscall` is a Linux system call number so this wouldn't work on macOS even if you got it to link.  Also, this is x86-64 code, not native ARM64, so you'd need `arch x86-64 ld ...` or something like that.  Use a tutorial for your OS and CPU.  (Or an x86-64 on Apple-Silicon guide to find out how to use x86-64 tutorials.)

Comment: Also, don't call `_start` from `main`, that's backwards.  If you define a `_start` at all, it's the process entry point.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://smist08.wordpress.com/2021/01/08/apple-m1-assembly-language-hello-world/)